# Is it possible to intialise a static variable dynamically in c?

Tags: c, static, dynamic-memory-allocation

I know that a **static variable** must be initialized with a **constant** because the value of the static variable must be known before the program starts running.

So can we say that **its not possible to initialize a static variable using dynamic memory allocation** as that means that the variable will be initialized while the program is running.

Also can someone please explain why the value of the **static variable** must be known before main starts running?

Comment: I am not sure `static` in your question really means `static`. If you have a `static` pointer, you can easily make it point to a dynamically allocated chunk of memory at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your title question: *Is it possible to intialise a static variable dynamically in c?*  The answer is no.  Details of why below...

The answer to your next question:

*"So can we say that its not possible to initialize a static variable using dynamic memory allocation..."*

is *yes, we can say that*,  because:

```
static int *array = calloc(5, sizeof(int));
```

will fail to compile, as the initializer element is not a compile-time constant.

The reason it will fail to compile is given in the *[C standard, N1570 paragraph 5.1.2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2)* where it clearly states:

> All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to their
> initial values) before program startup.

However, dynamically allocating memory to a properly initialized `static` variable *is* legal:

```
static int *array = NULL; //properly initialized static pointer variable.
...
array = calloc(5, sizeof(int));// legal
```

Answers to your final question: *why the value of the static variable must be known before main starts running?*

can be derived from *[These statements...](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-variables-in-c/)*

> 1. Static variables have a property of preserving their value even after they are out of their scope!  Hence, static variables preserve their ***previous value*** in their ***previous scope*** and are not initialized again in the new scope. *[emphasis mine]*

> 2. Static variables are ***allocated memory in data segment, not stack segment***. See memory layout of C programs for details.  *[emphasis mine]*

> 3. Static variables (like global variables) are initialized as 0 if not initialized explicitly. For example in the below program, value of x is printed as 0, while value of y is something garbage.*[see link for referenced program]*

So, by definition, because variables with *[static storage duration](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_storage_classes.htm)* exist during the entire life-time of the program, it makes sense that a known value exists in that memory space during the onset of run-time. (When `main()` starts running.)

Comment: None of the arguments are compelling -- yes, they preserve their value, but  what does that have to do with initialization? Yes, they reside typically in a "data segment", but still can be written to at arbitrary points in time, right? Yes, they are originally initialized with 0 but that does not prevent later overwriting with a different value. Proof: C++ is perfectly able to dynamically initialize static variables.

Comment: Also, "static storage <strike>scope</strike> is a confusing confusion of concepts. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to as `static` is ***[static storage duration.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/static_storage_duration)***.

Declaring a variable with static storage duration practically means that during linking, the linker will be the one allocating storage for the variable. When the linker is the one allocating storage, that means the variable will have a single address in the `.rodata` section (for constants) or the ˙.data˙, or `.bss` section.

The initial value of each static variable is written (hard-coded) in the executable and simply copied to the correct address by the loader before the `main()` function is called. This is mechanism is the reason these variables must be initialized by a constant value (or else they are zero-initialized).

Comment: That is all true but does not prevent dynamic run-time initialization (see C++).